# ViewPager not responding quickly

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

While using a ViewPager i noticed that it wouldn't respond very quickly, meaning that it slows down when switchting through fragments, kind of in a laggy way. 
**Does anyone know how this code could be causing the issue?**

```
public class List_adapter : BaseAdapter<Element>
{
    public List<Element> _list; 
    FragmentOne _context;


    public List_adapter(FragmentOne context, List<Element> list) 
    {                                                 
    super(context, list);                     
        _list = list;
        _context = context;
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() 
    {
        return _list.size();
    }
    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) 
    {
        return _list.get(position);
    }
    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) 
    {
        return getItem(position).hashCode();
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getActivity().getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false); 
        Element item = getItem(position);
        TextView lbl = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.label);
        TextView prop = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.Prop);
        lbl.setText(item.getlabel()); 
        prop.setText(item.getprop()); 
        return view; 
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Use [ViewHolder pattern](https://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html) for smooth list scrolling
2. Implement [Offscreen page limit](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#setOffscreenPageLimit(int)) for initialising a view before showing it inside `ViewPager`

Comment: The lag doesn't concern list scrolling, it occurs when switching through the various ViewPagers.
Also, i tried to implement Offscreen page limit but it didn't solve my problem.

Comment: Maybe you do too much in the main thread? Try to pass memory or CPU extensive operations to background threads. The problem is too inexact. Try [tracing](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/traceview.html) the code to see what causes lagging.

Comment: t's true that i do everything in the main thread but creating another thread wouldn't solve anything, beacuse the list is populated in the fragment's onCreateView method, and i tried to excecute it in another thread but it didn't do anything.